# What is the best practice to compose a scala class strucure with exchangable behaviour?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to write a Spark application that can extract data from several databases to different output formats. What is the best way to achieve something like that in Scala?

What I have for now is an abstract base class `DbExtractor`, that has all the attributes that are common for all databases. Then I have an abstract class for each database, e.g. `OracleDbExtractor`, that extends `DbExtractor`.

The `DbExtractor` defines some abstract functions that must be implemented by its subclasses (like `def saveOnHdfs(path: String): Long`)

These functions I want to implement in traits (e.g. `AvroOutput`) and then compose my final extractor like so:
`val ex = new OracleDbExtractor with AvroOutput`

Is this a good way to go?

Comment: what is the "exchangeable" (exchangable  is not a word, not a grammar nazi but just to let you know) part? you are just composing trait on the fly.. you can't change 'ex' instance  behavior later in the code

Comment: No I don't need to exchage the behaviour on the fly. I want to compose my `ex` with the desired behaviour and then let it do its work.

Comment: I want to have multiple storage options, e.g. `Avro`, `AvroWithHiveTable`, `Parquet` etc...
Each Format has a different Set of Parameters. How can I implement this on the DbExtractor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not in the correct way, let me explain.

How I see your problem, what I´ll do is next:

- Create a case class `case class DbExtractor(*Common Params*)`
- Inside the case class, create different defs `def oracleExtractor(*Especific Params*)`

Another solution is the use of Sqoop or other tools to transfer from databases.